# A funky scrolling layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, scroll

I am trying to adapt the layout demonstrated at http://www.webeffectual.com/ for my needs. I want these features:

1. `#toolbar` div to be fixed at the top of the browser window independent of any scrolling.
2. `#resultsLayer` to slide over `#introLayer` when scrolling
3. `#searchBar` to stick to the top but below #toolbar once `#searchbar` hits `#toolbar` while scrolling (just like the div containing 5 round colorful buttons sticks to the top of the window as demonstrated in http://www.webeffectual.com/, but in my case it should be below the #toolbar)
4. the `#resultsContainer` and all its children should slide under the `#searchBar` with further scrolling (just like the text in the pink layer of http://www.webeffectual.com slides under the navigation section)

so far I have achieved this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmaktu/ttnZa/2/) and it seems a steep road ahead:

1. got it working thanx to @HC_
2. achieved :)
3. got it working :) <del>but there is a gap between `#searchBar` and `#results`which gets filled on scrolling :(</del>
4. got this working too by setting a width on #searchBar <del>except for that gap</del>

`ul` tag had a margin set to 16px, set it to 0px n that got rid of the gap
got everything working :) Happy New Year to All! esp @HC_, hammered into new year!

Comment: I have done the work, see my fiddle, but because of some fault in my css positioning I am unable to get it right, so its a problem

Comment: This looks like it is really three to four feature requests, rather than a single question. My advice to you is to break your problems down into single questions that can be asked clearly and supply the code that pertains to them. Don't just provide links to external sites as these will be useless for future visitors once they have changed. You may make multiple posts here on SO, so take a more granular approach and I think you'll find the answers you receive to be much more helpful.

Comment: all problems here are entwined and related to a single layout as one div slides under another, if one issue is fixed someway others stop working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1a) Your toolbar needs to have a width set. Add `width:100px;` to get it to work

1b) Note that z-index does not work the way you most likely think it does, learn more [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

3) Probably just position with `position:fixed;` and a `top:50px;`

Overall though, just spend more time hammering away!

Comment: 1. is working ;), happy new year!